# framebuffers in osx

Tags: objective-c, macos, opengl, framebuffer

I am trying to start using framebuffers in my app. I fallowed Apple tutorial [Using a Framebuffer Object as a Texture](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/Conceptual/OpenGL-MacProgGuide/opengl_offscreen/opengl_offscreen.html). And my code looks like this:

Somewhere in header file:

```
GLuint framebuffer, texture;
GLenum status;
```

And .m file:

```
-(void)initFBO {
    glGenFramebuffersEXT(1, &framebuffer);
    glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, framebuffer);
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, width, height, 0,
                 GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
    glFramebufferTexture2DEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_EXT,
                              GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture, 0);
    status = glCheckFramebufferStatusEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT);
    if (status != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_EXT) {
        NSLog(@"failed");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"success");
    }
    glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, 0);
}

-(void)someDrawingFunc {
glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, framebuffer);
glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ZERO);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, someTexture);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex2f(0.0, height);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);;
    glVertex2f(0.0, 0.0);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex2f(width, 0.0);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex2f(width, height);
    glEnd();
glFlush();
glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, 0);

    [self drawFBO];
}

-(void)drawFBO {
glClearColor(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);
glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
glEnd();
glFlush();
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
}
```

In console I see "success", but in my app window I see:
[image]

And when I do `glReadPixels` and save them to image I get:
[image]

The size of saved image is as it should be, everything is OK, but I just get the `glClearColor` filled image with mysterious black line, and not what I have drawn to `framebuffer`

While with same code just without using framebuffer at all, in my app I see:
[image]

And when I save then, I see:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

---

So, framebuffer refuses textured GL_QUAD, that I am trying to draw, for some reason. So I guess problem has to be somewhere at framebuffer usage.

---

#### EDIT

Strange thing. When drawing fbo to screen now I see only red color (glClearColor where drawing FBO to screen), but when I do glReadPixels it reads pixels good. It saves image with my texture.

Default image (texture image, drawn to FBO):
[image]

What I see in my app window:
[image]

glReadPixels result image (texture readed from FBO and saved to file):
[image]

Yes, its upside down. Its normal for reading pixels from OpenGL. I updated code in question with that how my code looks like now

Comment: Do you enable depth testing anywhere in your application?

Comment: No I don't. Do I have to enable it?

Comment: No, not at all, but if it was enabled, it would be an error as you don't declare a depth buffer on the FBO.

Comment: It's done almost step by step identical to `Using a Framebuffer Object as a Texture` tutorial in apple documentation. No depth buffer, no depth testing. :)

Comment: Okay, did you try calling and evaluating [glGetError](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glGetError) after every call?

Comment: Actually not. But the `glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT)` returns `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE`, so I thing framebuffer initialization is OK, something wrong is only with how I use them. But I will try `glGetError` just right now

Comment: I use glGetError like this:

`GLenum errCode;
    const GLubyte *errString;
    
    if ((errCode = glGetError()) != GL_NO_ERROR) {
        errString = gluErrorString(errCode);
        fprintf (stderr, "OpenGL Error: %s\n", errString);
    }`

And I get `OpenGL Error: invalid enumerant`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15415/discussion-between-killiands-and-julius-petraska)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it. The problem was with my glTranslatef. I done `glPushMatrix()` and setted needed matrix parameters when rendering to FBO, and everything works fine now.